# how can i find cmake to download for android studio

Tags: android, c++, cmake

i want to use cmake which version is 14.0,but i can not find this version in android sdk manager[image]

i go to the cmake official website,and i find some cmake to download, like this:
https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/releases/tag/v3.14.0
but i cannot find android.toolchain.cmake script in theses version's cmake.

Is there some place to find 14.0 version cmake for android or am i misunderstand how to use it?

thanks advance~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the latest CMake, then you should use the official distribution of CMake.

There is no such thing as "CMake for android"

The `android.toolchain.cmake` file you're talking about is actually shipped inside the [NDK](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/master/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake)

Installing the NDK should be enough to have required CMake android configuration files.

As I can see from the screenshot, your NDK is not installed.

Comment: thank's your reply.actually i installed the ndk standalone and configue ndk.dir in local.properties file